# What is the meaning of "put a knot in your tail"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "put a knot in your tail" in the following sentence (Source: The great big elephant and the very small elephant),

> He stopped short. The Very Small Elephant stopped too. There in the
>   middle of the path stood Rinaldo. Rinaldo loved to fight.
>
> "If you try to pass here," he shout, "you will be sorry!"
>
> The Great Big Elephant was angry.
>
> "Get out of my way or I will put a knot in your tail.!"

?

Does "I will put a knot in your tail" mean  "I will bite your tail so that your tail will be hurt and you will have a lump(knot) in your tail" ?

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a source? Is it from a book about talking animals? I suspect the threat is to tie the tail into a knot.

Comment: Yes I could. It is from a book about talking animals(Elephant etc). Source: : The great big elephant and the very small elephant

Comment: When an elephant fights a Rinaldo, how do  elephant twist a Rinaldo's tail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elephant is almost certainly talking about tying Rinaldo's tail into a knot. The expression "put a knot in something" means pretty much the same thing as "tie something in a knot".

As to how an elephant could possibly accomplish such a feat, you can take your pick from either of these answers:

1. Artistic license. Elephants in the real world can't talk either.
2. With his trunk.